# How can use filters with a percolate query in Elasticsearch 5.1?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used a [percolator](https://www.elastic.co/blog/percolator) for reverse search in Elasticsearch version 5.1.

The problem I am facing now is how to add a filter query while searching the matched queries for the doc using percolator. I went through the Elasticsearch documentation, but I did not find any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out percolate can be used with a bool in Elasticsearch 5.x.
PFB example:

```
{
  "min_score": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "percolate": {
            "field": "query",
            "document_type": "doc_type",
            "type": "doc_type",
            "id": doc_id_for_scoring,
            "index": "index_name"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```